# Change the Code Using Pointers to Achieve Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: c++, object, oop, many-to-many

I have the following code in Movie.hpp

```
#ifndef MOVIE_H
#define  MOVIE_H

class Movie
{
  private:
    std::string title;
  public:
    std::string getTitle() const {return this->title;}  // const added 
    void setTitle(std::string newTitle){this->title = newTitle;}
};
#endif
```

In Actor.hpp

```
#ifndef ACTOR_H
#define  ACTOR_H

#include "Person.hpp"
#include "Movie.hpp"

class Actor: public Person
{
  private:
    std::vector<Movie> movieList;
  public:
    void addMovie(Movie newMovie){this->movieList.push_back(newMovie);}
    void printMovies()
    {
      for(Movie movie: this->movieList)
      {
        std::cout << movie.getTitle() << '\n';
      }
    }
};

#endif
```

In the Main executable file Main.cpp

```
 Movie movie1, movie2, movie3;        
  Comment comment1, comment2, comment3;
  Viewer viewer1, viewer2;
  Actor actor1, actor2;
  Celebrity celebrity1;

  movie1.setTitle("Transformers");
  movie2.setTitle("Interstellar");
  movie3.setTitle("The Matrix");

  actor1.setName("Brad");
  actor1.setAge(57);
  actor1.addMovie(movie1); //here
  actor1.addMovie(movie2);

  actor2.setName("Justin");
  actor2.setAge(30);
  actor2.addMovie(movie1);   // added
  actor2.addMovie(movie3);
```

Now, I have been instructed that my code is not following the many-to-many relationship. In other words, if actor1 and actor2 have a connection with the same movie, they should share the same 'Movie' object. In my case, they have different movie objects.
The proper way is to store pointers to Movie inside Actor:

```
std::vector<Movie*> movieList;
```

(collection of pointers, not of objects)

and inside Movie:

```
std::vector<Actor*> actorList;
```

Another proper way, I prefer this one, is to add a separate class

```
class Role {
private:
   Actor* actor;
   Movie* movie;
};
```

and store collection of such objects inside Movie and Actor, here values (not pointers)  are OK

```
std::vector<Role> movieList; //inside Actor

std::vector<Role> actorList; //inside Movie
```

So, the actual problem is I'm unable to implement above solution. Can someone please tell me the changes that will be made in previous code if I add pointer or Role object as instructed above ?

Comment: Using pointers into a vector can lead to problems when the vector is resized and the memory reallocated.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm there is another way by storing Role object as mentioned above. Can you please tell me the changes in the code after adding that  ?

Comment: *they should share the same 'Movie' object.* -- Try `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Movie>>` instead of `std::vector<Movie>` or `std::vector<Movie*>`.  Even your description cries out to use `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Can you please tell me what further changes will be there in the code after using shared_ptr ?

Comment: @SourabhRaha -- Will need to write a detailed answer for this.  So I won't really put this in the comment section.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Please write your proper answer then not in comments. I really need to implement this so your answer will be very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `Movie` object needs to be shared between `Actors`, another way to do this is to use `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Movie>>` instead of `std::vector<Movie>` or `std::vector<Movie*>`.

The reason why `std::vector<Movie>` would be difficult is basically what you've discovered.  The `Movie` object is separate from another `Movie` object, even if the `Movie` has the same name.

Then the reason why `std::vector<Movie*>` would be a problem is that yes, you can now "share" `Movie` objects, but the maintenance of keeping track of the number of shared `Movie` objects becomes cumbersome.

---

In comes `std::vector<std::shared<Movie>>` to help out.  The [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is not just a pointer, but a smart pointer, meaning that it will be a reference-counted pointer that will destroy itself when all references to the object go out of scope.  Thus no memory leaks, unlike if you used a raw `Movie*` and mismanaged it in some way.

```
#ifndef ACTOR_H
#define  ACTOR_H

#include "Person.hpp"
#include "Movie.hpp"
#include <memory>

class Actor: public Person
{
  private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Movie>> movieList;

  public:
    void addMovie(std::shared_ptr<Movie> newMovie) {this->movieList.push_back(newMovie);}

    void printMovies()
    {
      for(auto& movie: this->movieList)
      {
        std::cout << movie->getTitle() << '\n';
      }
    }
};

#endif
```

Then putting together a minimized version of your classes, and a test `main` function:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Movie
{
  private:
    std::string title;
    std::string m_rating = "G";
    
  public:
    std::string getTitle() const {return this->title;}  // const added 
    void setTitle(std::string newTitle){this->title = newTitle;}
    void setRating(std::string rating) { m_rating = rating; }
    std::string getRating() const { return m_rating; }
};

class Person {};

class Actor: public Person
{
  private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Movie>> movieList;

  public:
    void addMovie(std::shared_ptr<Movie> newMovie) {this->movieList.push_back(newMovie);}

    void printMovies()
    {
      for(auto& movie: movieList)
      {
        std::cout << movie->getTitle() << "  Rating: " << movie->getRating() << '\n';
      }
    }
};

int main()
{
  // Create our movies 
  auto movie1 = std::make_shared<Movie>();
  auto movie2 = std::make_shared<Movie>();
  auto movie3 = std::make_shared<Movie>();        

  Actor actor1, actor2;
  
  movie1->setTitle("Transformers");
  movie2->setTitle("Interstellar");
  movie3->setTitle("The Matrix");

  actor1.addMovie(movie1); 
  actor1.addMovie(movie2);

  actor2.addMovie(movie1); 
  actor2.addMovie(movie3);
  
  std::cout << "actor 1 movies:\n";
  actor1.printMovies();
  std::cout << "\nactor 2 movies:\n";
  actor2.printMovies();
  
  // Set the rating to movie1 to "R"
  movie1->setRating("R");

  std::cout << "\n\nactor 1 movies:\n";
  actor1.printMovies();
  std::cout << "\nactor 2 movies:\n";
  actor2.printMovies();
  
}
```

Output:

```
actor 1 movies:
Transformers  Rating: G
Interstellar  Rating: G

actor 2 movies:
Transformers  Rating: G
The Matrix  Rating: G


actor 1 movies:
Transformers  Rating: R
Interstellar  Rating: G

actor 2 movies:
Transformers  Rating: R
The Matrix  Rating: G
```

So now `actor1` and `actor2` now actually share the same `Movie` called "Transformers" -- they are no longer separate objects.  I added a `setRating` and `getRating` functions to demonstrate that changing the rating of `movie1` changed the rating to `R` for both `actor1` and `actor2`.

---

Now, nothing stops you from creating another movie with the same name (for example, a `movie4` with the name "Transformers").  If that is an issue, you will need an additional data structure that keeps track of the names that have already been used (probably a `std::unordered_set<std::string>`).  But that is a side point, and only stated just to let you know that this could happen.