# How to Change the Code After inserting Object in Vectors

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, pointers

In Movie.hpp

```
#ifndef MOVIE_H
#define  MOVIE_H

class Movie
{
  private:
    std::string title;
  public:
    std::string getTitle() const {return this->title;}   
    void setTitle(std::string newTitle){this->title = newTitle;}
};

#endif
```

In Actor.hpp

```
#ifndef ACTOR_H
#define  ACTOR_H

#include "Person.hpp"
#include "Movie.hpp"

class Actor: public Person
{
  private:
    std::vector<Movie> movieList;
  public:
    void addMovie(Movie newMovie){this->movieList.push_back(newMovie);}
    void printMovies()
    {
      for(Movie movie: this->movieList)
      {
        std::cout << movie.getTitle() << '\n';
      }
    }
};

#endif
```

What are the changes will be there in the code if I add a separate class

```
class Role {
private:
   Actor* actor;
   Movie* movie;
};
```

and store collection of such objects inside Movie and Actor

```
std::vector<Role> movieList; //inside Actor

std::vector<Role> actorList; //inside Movie
```

Someone please help me out by editing the code in Movie.hpp and Actor.hpp using the "Role" Object defined above.

Comment: Have you investigated using `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @user4581301 Yes I have done that but I need the code edited according to the instruction stated above that is by inserting Role object

Comment: How does this question differ from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67909738/change-the-code-using-pointers-to-achieve-many-to-many-relationship)?

Comment: Consider making a small program or two that you can use to experiment with `shared_ptr` (and other smart pointers so you can get a feel for what sort to use when). It is extremely hard to make good recommendations when we don't know how the classes will be used. Pointers of any sort might turn out to be the wrong way to do what you need done.

Comment: You could have one list of all movies, one list of all actors, and one list of Roles that acts as a key for a join. In this case you have three `vector`s of `unique_ptrs` and everyone else uses raw pointers to the objects in the `unique_ptr`s.

Comment: "*Someone please help me out by editing the code in Movie.hpp and Actor.hpp using the "Role" Object defined above*" - sounds like a homework assignment.  StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a homework server, or not a code writing service. What have you attempted so far to try to implement this yourself?

Comment: This is effectively your third cut at asking this question. In all three `shared_ptr` has been suggested. I strongly recommend experimenting with and asking questions about `shared-ptr`. Asking the same question over and over without showing any effort to implement the previously suggested solutions does not reflect well.

Comment: BTW, you only need the `this->` syntax when the member names are the same as the parameter names.  In that case, use a naming convention that differentiates member names from parameter names.  Some examples:  prefix member names with `m_` or add a suffix like `_` to the member names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll employ some database theory here.

Each movie will have a unique ID and a title:

```
class Movie
{
    unsigned int m_id;
    std::string  m_title;
  public:  
    Movie(unsigned int id, const std::string& title)
    : m_id(id), m_title(title)
    { ; }

    std::string get_title() { return m_title; }

    void set_title(const std::string& title)
    { m_title = title; }

    std::string get_id() {return m_id;}  

    void set_id(unsigned int id)
    { m_id = id;}

    bool order_by_id(const Movie& b)
    {
        return m_id <= b.m_id;
    }

    bool operator==(const Movie& b)
    {
        return (m_id == b.m_id) && (m_title == b.title);
    }
};
```

An `Actor` is a `Person` and has associations (acted in) zero or movies.  In this case, we'll have a container of *foreign keys* or `Movie` IDs.

```
class Actor : public Person
{
  public: 
    std::vector<unsigned int> movie_ids;
  //...
};
```

Now to have a database of movies:

```
std::vector<Movie> movie_database;
```

To find a movie containing an actor, you first get the movie ID from the actor:

```
Actor judy_g;
unsigned int judy_g_first_movie = judy_g.movie_ids[0];
```

Then you retrieve the movie from the database using the movie ID:

```
Movie judy_g_movie = movie_databases[judy_g_first_movie];
```

This technique is nice because you don't need to sort the movie database, you can use index tables instead:

```
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> role_index_table;
// Associate the role "major" with the first movie.
role_index_table["major"] = 0;
```

If it looks like a database and smells like a database, you should be using a database and not writing your own.

Comment: If this is heading where I think it is, `Role` will not hold pointers, instead it would hold the IDs. The IDs would be used to look up the `Movie`, possibly in a `map` or map-like container.

Comment: Yes, this technique uses IDs and Foreign keys because they can be easily transferred to a real database.  Also, the pointer method complicates things, especially ownership rules and deep copies.